# How bilinear interpolation works when down scaling?

Tags: image-processing, interpolation

I can clearly understand how bilinear interpolation works when up scaling the image, like fill the values while taking 4 nearest neighbours, but i can't understand how it works while down scaling the image. It would mean a lot to me if someone clarify for me.

Comment: It doesn't work very well at all.  You'd be better off using nearest neighbor.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm just learning it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaling an image requires mapping pixels from the input to pixels on the output.  If those pixel coordinates don't map to an integer, *interpolation* is required to estimate what the pixel value would have been.  The "Bi" part of bilinear means it's linear interpolation applied in two dimensions independently.  If for example output pixel 2,3 needs to come from input coordinates 1.5,7.2 you would interpolate in the X direction by taking 0.5 of each of the pixels at 1.0 and 2.0, then interpolate in the Y direction by taking 0.8 of the pixel at 7.0 and 0.2 of the pixel at 8.0.  Usually these operations are combined into a single set of equations, but they can be applied separately if needed.

Bilinear is a poor choice for downscaling because it leads to aliasing artifacts.  This is when you attempt to create spatial frequencies that are beyond the Nyquist sampling limit,  and high frequency detail turns into low frequency artifacts.  You can minimize this by blurring the image before you downscale it.  Or you can choose an interpolation algorithm that incorporates some low pass filtering.